# Using doParallel to start multiple system calls from R within a Slurm job

Tags: java, r, slurm, doparallel, system2

I am using an R script that basically pastes together commandline commands to execute through `system2()`. The commands run some Java application.

Now, I want to spawn multiple processes of that Java application at once, to execute some tasks on a cluster computer. The jobs are submitted via Slurm. Does it make sense to execute the system calls from within R using `doParallel` with the number of cores reserved for the Slurm job? Or are there more efficient options (e.g., run multiple instances of the R script in parallel through Slurm, in order to spawn the parallel Java instances)?

I am not sure how Slurm or `parallel` allocate resources and how to spawn the processes most efficiently. Which process will control where the Java instances are executed in this setup?

Example Slurm job:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=somejob
#SBATCH --output=somejob%a.out
#SBATCH --time=2:00:00
#SBATCH --partition=node
#SBATCH --qos=normal
#SBATCH --account=node
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=20
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=3200
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --array=1#-12

srun R --vanilla -f somescript.R
```

Example R script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

require("doParallel")

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(20)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach::foreach(
  arg1 = 1:20, .packages = "mypackage"
  ) %dopar% {
    arg2 <- "some_arg"
    system2("/path/to/java.exe", args = c(arg1, arg2), stdout = TRUE)
  }
```

Comment: sorry, no answer, just a few comments: 1. it is my understanding that slurm itself does not allocate resources, it just keeps track of how many resources are requested. The script executed needs to make sure to stick to the requested resources. 2. is there a particular reason why you paste together system commands with R instead of bash?

Comment: @starja Hi, the reason I do it like that is that there is an R package that does most of the work out of the box (it was written to make the Java tool available from R) and I can use R to prepare a few things. E.g., I can read input data and make adjustments to the system commands based on that.
So, I understand that Slurm provides as many resources as requested, and, ideally R manages them...

Comment: I see. Yes, then R needs to manage the resources, however, I think calling a java tool makes it a bit complicated. `registerDoParallel` uses shared memory by default ("fork") which can be an advantage if your processed data is very big and needs to be used by every worker process. However, I think in the end it depends on how the java tools uses the CPUs/memory, not sure how easy it is to manage this from R

Answer (score 0):

The following R script and shell script will run 2 R sessions, each using 32 cores, for 64 parallel executions of your Java code. You can also modify to suit a different cluster nodes and cores configuration.

```r
library(mypackage) # substitute your package name and add others
library(pbdMPI)

my_arg1 = comm.chunk(64, form = "vector") # gets arg1 instances for this rank

sys_call = function(arg1) {
    arg2 <- "some_arg"
    system2("/path/to/java.exe", args = c(arg1, arg2), stdout = TRUE)
}
mclapply(my_arg1, sys_call, mc.cores = 32)

finalize()
```

Save the above in `my_r_script.R`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --exclusive

module load r

mpirun  --map-by ppr:1:node Rscript my_r_script.R
```

Save the above in `my_script.sh` and submit to Slurm with `sbatch my_script.sh`.

The shell script asks for 2 nodes and all cores on the nodes. The OpenMPI `mpirun` places 1 R session per node and because of exclusive access all cores are available for `mclapply()`.

You may need to load modules that provide your software environment, including `module load r`. These details are usually site-dependent.

You will need additional `#SBATCH` parameters for account, queue, time, and possibly memory, which may vary on different clusters with different local defaults.

Your `arg1` parameter is different in each of the 64 instances and can be used to create different output file names in your Java code.